# Elasticsearch: Disabling Shield After License Expiration (Safely)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-shield

I started using the Shield plugin for security, but then moved to a NGINX reverse proxy. I now have both Shield and NGINX running, but my Shield license expired.

How do I turn off Shield without interrupting the cluster (2 nodes)?

I tried uninstalling the Shield plugin, and that did not do anything. It just removed the admin tools, but the underlying authentication continued to function.

I have the following Shield config files, but I'm afraid that just deleting them may hurt the cluster:

```
$ ls /etc/elasticsearch/shield/
logging.yml           roles.yml      users.new
logging.yml.new       roles.yml.new  users_roles
role_mapping.yml      system_key     users_roles.new
role_mapping.yml.new  users
```

Comment: How did you uninstall the plugin? did you get any error message?

Comment: To uninstall Shield:


- Shut down Elasticsearch. 


                     service elasticsearch stop


- Go to:
                      cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
- Remove the Shield plugin from Elasticsearch: 
                      bin/plugin remove shield
- Restart Elasticsearch. 
                     service elasticsearch restart